# Create ASB MessagingFactory from connection string and provide settings

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus

I want to create an Azure Service Bus `MessagingFactory` instance from a connection string **and** specific the `BatchFlushInterval` setting.

The factory method on `MessagingFactory` that takes a connection string does **not** take a `MessagingFactorySettings` instance.

The factory method on `MessagingFactory` that takes a `MessagingFactorySettings` instance does **not** take a connection string.

The closest I've come is this:

`var connectionStringBuilder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
var messagingSettings = new MessagingFactorySetttings
{
    TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(connectionStringBuilder.SharedSecretIssuerName, connectionStringBuilder.SharedSecretIssuerSecret),
    NetMessagingTransportSettings =
    {
        BatchFlushInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100) // <-- This is the setting I want to specify.
    }
};
var messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionStringBuilder.Endpoints, messagingSettings);`

But that only works if you know that's the specific token provider information provided in the connection string. If it does something else, like use one of the other five methods of providing tokens, then this code fails.

How can you create a `MessagingFactory` instance from a connection string **and** specify the `BatchFlushInterval`?

Comment: I think you did it right. you can't modify the `MessagingFactorySettings` after the `MessagingFactory` is created.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to do this? I'm struggling with the same thing.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be possible. But I haven't looked since the time, so you never know.

Answer (score 4):

The way I found to do it is by using the token provider from the namespace manager. So:

```
var namespaceMngr = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(namespaceConnString);
MessagingFactorySettings mfs = new MessagingFactorySettings();
mfs.TokenProvider = namespaceMngr.Settings.TokenProvider;
mfs.NetMessagingTransportSettings.BatchFlushInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeToFlush);
MessagingFactory mf = MessagingFactory.Create(namespaceMngr.Address, mfs);
```

If you are trying to set the `AmqpTransportSettings.BatchFlushInterval` instead of the `NetMessagingTransportSettings.BatchFlushInterval` then I can't help you, I actually stumbled on this post looking for an answer. Trying to change the `AmqpTransportSettings.BatchFlushInterval` doesn't seem to stick to the `MessageFactory` even if the `MessageFactorySettings` reflect the change.

Comment: This works but seems to have the annoying sideeffect that the namespaceMngr.Address has port 9355 instead of the 9354 I get by using TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString().

Answer (score 0):

JordanSchillers answer fixes the token provider issue but my address was now using port 9355 instead of 9354.

I ended using a mixture of the ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder and the NamespaceManager:

```
        var serviceBusConnectionString = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(connection.ConnectionString);
        MessagingFactorySettings factorySettings = new MessagingFactorySettings();
        factorySettings.TransportType = serviceBusConnectionString.TransportType;
        //Use the  namespacemanager to create the token provider.
        var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connection.ConnectionString);
        factorySettings.TokenProvider = namespaceManager.Settings.TokenProvider;
        factorySettings.NetMessagingTransportSettings.BatchFlushInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(batchTimeInMs);

        MessagingFactory factory = MessagingFactory.Create(serviceBusConnectionString.Endpoints, factorySettings);
        return factory.CreateTopicClient(topicName);
```